# Mysql Optimization for joining tables with latest changes

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I am kind of a beginner on MYSQL and I have this Query that is taking about 4-7 seconds and i need to optimize it, with your help!

### My tables are:

**cheques_movimientos** ("status changes or movements" of the checks)
**cheques_movimientos_rel** (Relational table of Checks and "status changes or movements")
**payments_cheques** (check list, without status)

The Query is selecting the latest status and joining with the check table, and if doesn't have any status change it means that it should be status 10.

I need a list of the checks with any the latest status changes of 10,15,40,70,80.

[Here is the SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7dddb7/1)

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


CREATE TABLE `payments_cheques` (
  `id` int(9) NOT NULL,
  `venta_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `moneda` varchar(3) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
  `valor` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `banco` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `numero` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `cruzado` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `primer_beneficiario` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `almacen_id` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `llamar_antes` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;


INSERT INTO `payments_cheques` (`id`, `venta_id`, `fecha`, `moneda`, `valor`, `banco`, `numero`, `cruzado`, `primer_beneficiario`, `almacen_id`, `llamar_antes`) VALUES
(685, 1150, '2021-03-16', 'COP', 2500000, '1', '17002', 0, 0, 1, NULL),
(682, 1167, '2021-03-05', 'COP', 3300000, '51', '0387-1', 0, 0, 1, NULL),
(680, 1193, '2021-02-04', 'COP', 1050000, '7', 'MP8138', 0, 0, 1, NULL),
(678, 1143, '2021-02-02', 'COP', 1500000, '51', '5/58005', 0, 0, 1, NULL),
(677, 1120, '2021-01-25', 'COP', 3300000, '7', '07/00006', 0, 0, 1, NULL),
(676, 1199, '2020-12-30', 'COP', 3000000, '1', '89123', 0, 0, 1, NULL),
(675, 1297, '2020-12-29', 'COP', 3500000, '1', '39302', 0, 0, 1, NULL),
(673, 1124, '2020-12-23', 'COP', 1400000, '13', '418626', 0, 0, 1, NULL),
(671, 1219, '2021-03-01', 'COP', 1000000, '7', 'AF8398', 0, 0, 1,  NULL),
(670, 1129, '2020-12-23', 'COP', 900000, '7', 'AF7396', 0, 0, 1,  NULL);



ALTER TABLE `payments_cheques`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `payments_cheques`
  MODIFY `id` int(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=686;
  

CREATE TABLE `cheques_movimientos_rel` (
  `cheque_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `movimiento_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `cheques_movimientos_rel` (`cheque_id`, `movimiento_id`) VALUES
(680, 198),
(678, 197),
(677, 196),
(676, 194),
(675, 194),
(673, 189),
(671, 200),
(670, 188);


ALTER TABLE `cheques_movimientos_rel`
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `Movimiento_Cheque` (`movimiento_id`,`cheque_id`);



CREATE TABLE `cheques_movimientos` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `userid` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  `fecha` date NOT NULL,
  `tipo` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `caja_movimiento_id` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `cheques_movimientos` (`id`, `userid`, `timestamp`, `fecha`, `tipo`, `caja_movimiento_id`) VALUES
(200, 1, '2021-03-04 17:24:28', '2021-03-04', '1', NULL),
(198, 1, '2021-02-12 15:15:40', '2021-02-12', '30', 14783),
(197, 1, '2021-02-08 15:17:13', '2021-02-08', '60', 14692),
(196, 1, '2021-01-27 17:27:49', '2021-01-27', '30', 14543),
(194, 1, '2020-12-30 16:08:05', '2020-12-30', '30', 14339),
(189, 1, '2020-12-29 11:19:20', '2020-12-29', '70', NULL),
(188, 1, '2020-12-29 11:18:47', '2020-12-29', '30', 14301);



ALTER TABLE `cheques_movimientos`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `grupo` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `cheques_movimientos`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=203;

COMMIT;
```

This is the Query I use:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT payments_cheques.*, IFNULL(cheques.tipo,'10') as status from `payments_cheques` LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT a.*
    FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT 
                `payments_cheques`.`id`,
                `cheques_movimientos`.`id` as `mov_id`,
                `cheques_movimientos`.`tipo`
            FROM `payments_cheques`
            JOIN `cheques_movimientos_rel` ON `payments_cheques`.`id` = `cheques_movimientos_rel`.`cheque_id`
            JOIN `cheques_movimientos` ON `cheques_movimientos_rel`.`movimiento_id` = `cheques_movimientos`.`id`) as aa WHERE tipo != '1') as a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT 
                `payments_cheques`.`id`,
                `cheques_movimientos`.`id` as `mov_id`,
                `cheques_movimientos`.`tipo`
            FROM `payments_cheques`
            JOIN `cheques_movimientos_rel` ON `payments_cheques`.`id` = `cheques_movimientos_rel`.`cheque_id`
            JOIN `cheques_movimientos` ON `cheques_movimientos_rel`.`movimiento_id` = `cheques_movimientos`.`id`) as bb WHERE tipo != '1') as b
        ON a.id = b.id AND a.mov_id < b.mov_id
    WHERE b.id IS NULL and a.`tipo` != '1') as cheques
ON payments_cheques.id = cheques.id) as t1
WHERE status IN (10,15,40,70,80)
```

EDIT:
I fixed the missing ID, this is a sample database, the real one is about 500 IDs.

What I need is a list of checks that has the status of 10,15,40,70,80 being 10 the status without any movements or status changes.

This is the story behind:
I receive checks from my customers and then I deposit or cash the check, but first. I need the list of available checks that i can use.

After I deposit the check and log the movement and assign it to the check but i dont keep the latest status of the

Comment: Can you paste the fiddle statements here

Comment: @Strawberry I just edited it.

Comment: That query has at least 2 extra levels of nesting.  Please rewrite it to use fewer level.  (Then we can work on further optimization.)

Answer (score 0):

That query is really bad.

> I need a list of the checks with any the latest status changes of 10,15,40,70,80.

Then that's your starting point. It's a FAQ. It even has it's [own page in the MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html) describing 2 of the methods for getting the results. There is another method not described there which a bit messy as it [relies on lots padding and type conversions](https://kristiannielsen.livejournal.com/6745.html).

Looking at your schema cheques_movimientos_rel appears to be adding no value but is adding a lot of cost to your queries.

Answer (score 0):

NOT YET AN ANSWER, but more than a comment would allow.

You have provided a bunch to work with... table structures, query (even as bad as it is) and even sample data.

The sample data you have provided is somewhat ok and looking at it have determined the relationships between them respectively are

```
payments_cheques pc
    JOIN cheques_movimientos_rel cmr
            ON pc.id = cmr.cheque_id
            JOIN cheques_movimientos cm
                ON cmr.movimiento_id = cm.id
```

That said, looking at the data, there are some entries that have entries in payments_cheques that are NOT in cheques_movimentos_rel table such as ID 671, 682, 685.

The inverse is true also... entries in cheques_movimentos_rel that do not exist in payments_cheques such as 671, 681

Similarly in cheques_movimientos has entries that are not in the cheques_movimentos_rel table including 192, 193 and 195.

Can you please **edit your post** that can clarify why such Ids may be missing in either of the respective tables.  Additionally, in simple sentences, describe what you are TRYING TO DO, regardless of the query. Ex: I am looking for all xxx where blah, blah, etc.  If no record matches blah, blah, I need to do zzz.

You are also comparing for TIPO != '1' and there are no such entries even present with a type of '1' unless that is the basis of your left join.  Given more information, you probably will be able to get a solution.

Comment: Hello, I edited  the post. thanks for your reply